# Windows 2008 Server on VMWare (hardware)

Tags: vmware-esxi

I want to setup a single server to run a few virtual servers for our datacenter. I do not have a lot of money to spend so I am trying to gain bang for the buck. My budget is around $2,000.

So I was thinking about building the following as the VMWare physical server:

- Intel iCore 7 950 (LGA1366, 4 cores,8 threads)
- Gigabyte GA-X58-USB3 LGA 1366 X58 ATX Intel Motherboard
- 24 GB of Viper II Series, Sector 7 Edition, Extreme Performance DDR3-1600
  (PC3-12800) CL9 Triple Channel Memory
- VelociRaptor 300GB 10,000 RPM SATA 3.0Gb/s 3.5" Internal Hard Drive

I am planning on running the newest version of VMWare ESXi (64-bit).

On these I am planning on running a few various servers:

- Windows 2008 Server R2 w/ IIS (several custom built ASP.NET Apps)
- Windows 2008 Server R2 w/ MS SQL 2008 Database Server
- Linux Web Server w/ Several WordPress Blogs (XAMPP?)
- Windows 2008 Server R2 w/ IIS (DEV ENVIRONMENT)
- Windows 2008 Server R2 w/ MS SQL 2008 Database Server (DEV ENVIRONMENT)

In your opinion, will this hardware be sufficient to run the above load with room for possible 2-3 more virtual machines (probably lightweight web servers)?

Comment: two data base server might be a little steep, but it depends on what they are for

Answer (score 4):

The motherboard, and thus the disk and network controllers in your spec, are not on the [HCL](http://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php) so are unlikely to work, either at all, stably or with support. Their HCL is notoriously, and justifiably, short.

Other than that your guest load shouldn't be too bad but you won't see anything like bare-metal performance but if you're not expecting production load it would suffice as a dev box. If it worked at all of course.

Comment: Almost all the comments mention IF this runs, it should not be in production. If I get this running on a whitebox configuration, am I going to have stability issue with this platform? What type of problems might I encounter that would prevent running in PROD?

Answer (score 0):

As previously indicated if the server will not be in the HCL list it will not be supported by VMware. However, you can setup a server called whitebox - you'll be able to install VMware's ESXi on it and run. Based on the amount indicated, you should be able to get such as server.

Look through those sites to check for the hardware:
http://tinyurl.com/y8jfaoe

Needless to say, the system you'll be building shouldn't be in production.